# Making Kiddush Hoshanah Rabah morning

Tags: kiddush, hoshana-rabbah

My family has a Minhag (practice) to make [Kiddush](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiddush) [Hoshanah Raba](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoshana_Rabbah) morning before the meal. 
does anyone know if there's a source to this Minhag and what it is?

Comment: Welcome Alex F: Thanks for bringing your question to this site. I have never heard of anyone making Kiddush prior to the Seuda on Hoshana Raba. I looked through the Nitei Gavriel, who is pretty thorough with all different Minhagim and he does not mention anything about this. When did this Minhag start? Did your father's father do this?

Comment: What is is the nusach of this kiddush? Could it be that he was just particular to have wine with his seudah on this day of chol hamoed? It is right to have a meal with meat and wine of chol hamoed.

Comment: My fathers father did it and all my uncles do as well. my grandfather passed away young so I don't know from where he took the Minhag.. The Nussach is the typical Yum Tov morning Kiddush, starting with Aile Moadai and proceeding with Hagofen..

Answer (score 2):

The Spinka chassidim apparently have a custom to make kiddish on Hoshanah Rabbah. They originate from Romania. Here is a link from a Spinka kiddish from this year...
http://youtu.be/D8fLdoT67yE

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinka_(Hasidic_dynasty)

Looking a little further, in the siddur of Rabbi Shabbtai of Rashkov for the Regalim, there is a unique kavanah for each of the seven days to be made for the blessing of "leishev b'Sukkah". This is said at the meal. It doesn't offer a proof of making a kiddish like for Yom Tov. But clearly indicates that a meal that is distinct to that day is made.

Regarding the minhag of Spinka as it relates both to Sukkot and Hoshannah Rabbah, it can be found in Sefer Eish Tamid which was written by the 2nd Rebbe of Spinka, Admor Yitzchok Isaac Weiss, the author of Chakal Yitzchok. There in chapter 60, pg 343:4-5, chapter 62, pg 346:2 and chapter 63:352:14, it says that for all the days of the chag after the first day of the Yom Tov, they do not make the blessing of "leishev b'Sukkah" except for 15 times corresponding to the 15 required meals. It explains that this is to fulfill the required obligation to eat 14 meals according to the view of the Tanna Kama, Rabbi Eliezer in the Mishnah in Sukkah 27a.

The details of "seudah kavuah", the fixed obligatory meal of the festival mean bread, wine and meat. This follows the explanation of Rambam in Sefer HaMitzvot, positive mitzvot, mitzvah 54 which says that the concept of rejoicing in your festival, one of the specific commandments for Sukkot, is to eat meat and drink wine. This is also brought in Sefer Ta'amei HaMinhagim v'Makorei HaDinim, pg 345:787. It explains that the concept of dwelling in the sukkah means eating and drinking. According to many, it is more mehuddar to say the blessing of "leishev b'Sukkah" over a cup of wine and to say it standing.

But all this doesn't distinguish Hoshannah Rabbah. The minhag of Spinka regarding the meals applies to all the days.

Sefer Ta'amei HaMinhagim v'Makorei HaDinim, pg 354, sief 811:11-12 compares Hoshannah Rabbah to both Shabbat, being the 7th day and to Yom Kippur, in that it is the completion of the cycle that began from Rosh Chodesh Elul. This is alluded to in the actual word הושענא. The salvation occurs at the completion of the 51 day cycle from the first day of Rosh Chodesh Elul through Hoshannah Rabbah.

Similarly, the Avudarham, Tefillat Sukkah, beginning with the words, "And on the 5th day of chol hamoed, which is Hoshannah Rabbah", it explains that there are those who have the custom to add the Yotzer of Shabbat, and the kedushah of Musaph  Shabbat to the Hoshannah Rabbah prayers like is done for Yom Tov even though it is chol hamoed. The Avudarham says the minhag is to think of Hoshannah Rabbah like a Yom Tov and like the sealing of Yom Kippur. This idea is also brought in Pri Megadim 664 and is discussed by the Levush to the same siman (664, sief 1). This same practice is also brought in Sefer Tzedah l'Derech, Ma'amar 4, K'lal 6, chapter 9. And the additions outlined by the Avudarham are also what is specified in the minhagim of Spinka.

Comment: Do you have a source that Spinka chassidim make kiddush on Hoshanah Rabba? That video does not show them making kiddush. It just shows them eating on the sukkah and calls the meal a "kiddush"

Comment: @Daniel: You've seen what I found so far. If you look at the associated You Tube video it also mentions a Tish for Leil Hoshannah Rabbah.

Comment: So how do you know they have a custom to make kiddush on Hoshanah Rabbah?

Comment: It's their label. I don't think they would call it that if it's not how they think of it. But that said, I point you to the source from Rabbi Shabtai I mentioned. It' possible there is a specific kiddush for each day of the festival paralleling the kavanot.

Comment: @Daniel: I may have just found a sefer specifically on minhagim Spinka. Bli neder, I'll call the seller to see if it's still available and if so, purchase it. That should probably put your concerns to rest.

Comment: That would be a great addition to the answer if it's in there. Perhaps while you have the author on the phone you could ask the question directly

Comment: The video is quite interesting. I wish I understood Yiddish better! Who is the person, BTW. If he is the "official" Spinker Rebbe, he looks very young! I also echo what @Daniel has been "harping" on - both b/c there is no official "Kiddush" / blessing being shown in the video and b/c he has the same first name as me ;-)

Comment: @DanF According to the Wikipedia page linked in the answer, there are many Spinka Rebbes.

Comment: The book is called "Sefer Aish Tamid - Minhagei Spinka for the entire year. It was written by Rabbi Chaim Joseph Halevi Friedman who is listed on Wikipedia from the Ulemer branch of Spinka and is known was the Brezaner Rav. From the table of contents, there are quite a few pages devoted specifically to Hoshanna Rabbah. I was told it should arrive sometime next week.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check out that book? Does it say anything about kiddush?

Comment: Still interested in hearing about that book. Did it have any interesting information?

Comment: @Daniel: I edited the initial reply. Info was included there since October 8.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Ah thanks I missed that. So it seems that they don't actually say kiddush on _hoshanah rabbah_ although they are _makpid_ to say _leisheiv b'sukkah_ on wine.

Comment: @Daniel: It depends upon how you define "kiddush". They mention z'man in the context of "leshev b'sukkah" and do it over a kos bracha specifically. And they do say based upon their understanding of the mishnah that it is required from the Tanai'im. They also recognize that Hoshannah Rabbah is not like the other days of Chol HaMoed. It's more like Shabbat and Yom Tov. Surprisingly, since it relates it as a parallel to Pesach, it corresponds with the 7th of Pesach which is actually a Yom Tov.

Comment: @YaacovDeane That's an interesting point about mentioning the z'man. I think you have material for a very interesting answer. I'd recommend editing your answer to remove some of the less relevant information and focusing on what you found in the book. I would also mention in your answer that the nusach of the kiddush doesn't match what OP's family does.

Comment: @Daniel: Who or what is "OP"?

Comment: @YaacovDeane OP means "original poster" meaning the person who posted the question.